# Search from mysql column

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I Have a post from where you can select which category your post will belong to.
You can select max 5 different category (tags).

It saves these tags to same column to mysql.

```
id   user    title    body             tags                     Date
1     6    Functions  ....    javascript,jquery,html,mysql   2016-07-27
```

---

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
user    TEXT,
title   TEXT, 
body    TEXT, 
tags    TEXT, 
date    DATE,
```

If user search for javascript posts it should show all posts that have javascript tag included to tag column.
How do I make the mysql select with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the other answers will most likely work but you should consider normalizing the table. Storing this as a csv will get hard to support.

Remove the `tags` column from what I will call your `post` table resulting in (you should consider storing a `user_id` over a `name`):

```
+----+------+-----------+------+------------+
| id | user |   title   | body |    Date    |
+----+------+-----------+------+------------+
|  1 | Tony | Functions | .... | 2016-07-27 |
+----+------+-----------+------+------------+
```

Now create a `post_category` table which would be filled like this.

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | post_id |    tag     |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | 1       | javascript |
|  2 | 1       | jquery     |
|  3 | 1       | html       |
|  4 | 1       | mysql      |
+----+---------+------------+
```

The `post_id` is a `foreign key` to the `post` table's `id` column.

Now you can do a query like (not tested):

```
SELECT post.* FROM post
#Joins are intimidating at first 
#but a pretty important concept to learn
JOIN post_category ON post.id = post_category.post_id
WHERE post_category.tag LIKE '%javascript%'
```

Creating a table `tag` would also be recommendable so you can control the tags users can use. It would be similar to the above. If you want an example let me know.

**Additional info for comment**

Since you are getting a string of csv to `INSERT` you can do something like this:

```
//Create your post and get the id.
$string = "javascript,jquery,html,mysql";
$post_cats = explode(',', $string); //This is an array broken at ,
foreach($post_cats as $post_cat){
    //Do your insert with $post_cat it is a string and the post_id you have
}
```

**Additional info for comment about tag table**

The table would not be hard to create. It would be an `Id` that is a `primary key` and a `name` potentially a `description` but I will leave that off for now.

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |javascript |
|  2 |jquery     |
|  3 |html       |
|  4 |mysql      |
+----+-----------+
```

Now you will simply update your `post_category` table to have a `tag_id` as a `foreign key` to `tag` table's `id`

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id |tag_id  |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | 1       | 1      |
|  2 | 1       | 2      |
|  3 | 1       | 3      |
|  4 | 1       | 4      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Now your query becomes (not tested)

```
SELECT post.* FROM post
JOIN post_category ON post.id = post_category.post_id
JOIN tag ON tag.id = post_category.tag_id
WHERE post_category.post_id = 1
```

The trick is giving the user the interface to select the multiple tags but that is another topic all together.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use that

Comment: How do I do the Mysql `post_category` INSERT in post form. I have a string like this `javascipt,jquery,php`. Do I have to make 3 different mysqli query?

Comment: You wouldn't need the `LIKE` clause any more if you did this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard since it is a string and not a table driven one I figured to catch some beginning and trailing issues this would be better to try match.

Comment: It would be cool to make the tag table so users cant make any stupid categorys @nerdlyist

Comment: @Tonza it would be cool. Check out the update. This is all untested while in a meeting but should be good enough to get you moving.

Comment: @nerdlyist One more question ;) If I use `join` in mysql select to connect `user table` and `post table` I'm using the same method as your example. But both table have column that have same name `date` if I use `echo $row['date']` It only echo the `date` that is in the `user table` how I can access to `date` that is in the `post table` I hope you understand it

Comment: To do that you can alias them and will need to call out the specific table. For example of date you could do `SELECT post.date AS post_date ...` then access it in the array with that key.

Answer (score 3):

You use a [wildcard search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)...

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%javascript%'
```

But you may want to reconsider your table layout, making it more normal.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tags LIKE '%javascript%';
```

Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use find in set for mySQL

[FIND_IN_SET DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * from table where FIND_IN_SET('javascript',tags)>0;
```

But I'm not a big fan of the table layout.  Normalized data for databases and storing multiple values in 1 column isn't normalized.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) mysql function.

```
select * from my_table where find_in_set('javascript', tags) > 0;
```

Note that `find_in_set()` function is case-insensitive so using `javascript` or `Javascript` in above query will produce the same result.

If you want to use it for multiple values, you can use `OR` in the where clause:

```
select * from my_table where find_in_set('javascript', tags) > 0 or find_in_set('MySql', tags) > 0;
```